# ReferenceError: prettyPrint is not defined error

Tags: javascript, google-code-prettify

Hope you can help me with `ReferenceError: prettyPrint is not defined`.

```
<a class="question helpcenterheading" href="http://www.google.com">How do I contact you?</a>
<span class="answer">One moment...</span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span.answer").hide();
    $("a.question").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(2000, function() {
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

([live version](http://ognjendivljak.com/jb/one.html))

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted) there are two ways to run Prettify:

1) The auto-loader `run_prettify.js`. This doesn't require you to call any functions, you can specify some parameters in the URL.

2) Serving your own JS and CSS, by loading `prettify.css` and `prettify.js`. Then you need to use `<body onload="prettyPrint()">`.

I think you're using the auto-loader, and then trying to call `prettyPrint()`. Pick one or the other method, you can't mix them.

Answer (score 5):

You have

```
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
```

But prettyPrint is never defined